# Static elements in Flex CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm beginner in frontend, and I've a problem.
This is a small cite on Flex. I want menu items to change font style from regular to italic, but with style changing width of item is changing too. So at :hoover case all the menu starts to rock)
How I can improve this?
I can't find the right solution to make menu items static, not moving in flex construction.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,700;1,400;1,500&display=swap');
body {
  margin: 0em;
  font-family: Lora;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
}

p {
  margin: 0em;
  text-indent: 1.5em;
  text-align: justify;
}

header {
  align-content: stretch;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 25%;
  padding-top: 2em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: ;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 500;
  height: 1em;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
}

.logo:hover {
  font-style: italic;
}

.logo__description {
  margin-top: 1em;
  width: 30em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  margin-left: 2em;
  margin-right: 2em;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: left;
  /*border-left: 2px solid black;
      border-right: 2px solid black;
      border-block-start s;
      border-radius: 4px;*/
}

menu {
  padding-top: 1.5em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  column-gap: 1em;
  row-gap: 1em;
  margin: 0em;
  padding-left: 0em;
}

.menu__item {
  height: 2em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 500;
  height: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px;
  width: auto;
}

.menu__item:hover {
  font-style: italic;
  color: darkslategrey;
  width: inherit;
}

.menu__item:focus {
  font-style: italic;
  color: darkslategrey;
}

.about {
  width: 60%;
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="logo">
      Essential
    </div>
    <div class="logo__description">
      <p>Образовательный проект, посвящённый созданию музыки, поиску новых подходов, способов сочинения, а также психологии, эвристике и философии творчества.</p>
    </div>
    <menu>
      <a href="" class="menu__item" style="font-style: italic;">
                  О проекте
              </a>
      <a href="" class="menu__item">
                  Статьи
              </a>
      <a href="https://vk.cc/c3Bd9D" class="menu__item">
        <div class="course">Записаться на курс</div>
      </a>
    </menu>
  </header>
  <div class="about">
    <p>Привет! Меня зовут Данила, я звукорежиссёр и композитор. Хочу рассказать о первом образовательном курсе, который я хочу осуществить.</p>
    <p>Этот курс имеет своей целью пробудить творческие возможности в звуке у всех, вне зависимости от уровня владения музыкальным софтом или инструментами.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you put this on fiddle and share? It will be easier to debug

Comment: Something seems wrong as if your font-family does not have italicized version, Not all fonts have italicized characters. Or, you might be in a situation where the italic version of the font isn’t loaded. In either case, the browser will try to fake it anyway, which almost always looks awful (or at least much worse than using an actual italic font). Its not that your font-size is changing but letter themselves are changing

Comment: Hello, I think the only way to fix the change of the width is to remove font-style: italic; from :hover